# Arduino IR door

Tags: arduino, infrared

i want to make an IR sensor door with DFRobot IRsensor (switch) and Servo. the problem is in the if statement because the digitalread is always changing when there's nothing in front of the IR sensor which is the way it suppouse to be... so it rapidly closing and opening. but i want the door to be open when there's something in front of the sensor and then some delay, then its gonna close if there's something (new) in front of the door.

mycode:

```
    #include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;// create servo object to control a servo 
            // a maximum of eight servo objects can be created 
int IRsensor =8;

int pos = 180;    // variable to store the servo position 
int d;
boolean kondisi;


void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
  pinMode (IRsensor,INPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);
} 


void loop() 
 { 
  d = digitalRead (IRsensor);
  bukatutup (d);
  delay (15);
}

void bukatutup(int IR)
{
  Serial.println (IR);
  if (IR == 0 and (kondisi == false))
 {
   pos = 0;
   Serial.println ("terbuka");
  myservo.write (pos);
  kondisi == true;
  delay(1000);
  }
  else if ( IR == 0 and (kondisi == true))
{
   pos = 180;
   Serial.println ("tertutup");
   kondisi == false;
   myservo.write (pos);
   delay (1000);
  }
 }
```

Thx,

Comment: So you need to introduce a delay, is that the problem? Detect something, open the door, but only close when nothing has been detected for a certain amount of time?

Comment: no, iwant the door to close when there's something (new) infront of the door

Comment: Ok, sorry. But then you want the door to stay closed until nothing has been seen in front of the door for some time, is that the issue?

Comment: let me make it clear, first the sensor goes on (there's something)(the door open) and then it off (there's nothing) (the door keep opening) and then if it goes on again (there's something new) it will be closed

Comment: And what would you like to happen when the sensor is tripped for the third time?  So sensor trips once: open door. Then nothing is detected: prepare to close door. Something is detected: close door. What needs to happen when something is detected again, now that the door is closed?

Comment: its open again like the first time

Comment: OK, so let me make sure I have this right. Something is detected: open the door. Wait for some time.  Now when something is detected, close the door. Wait for some time.  Now when something is detected, open the door.  Repeat _ad nauseum_. Yes?